# How to pipe a quit/exit to a curl command that is using telnet

Tags: bash, curl, telnet

For systems that have telnet disabled (most systems in production), curl is often used instead in order to get around this limitation.

How can an exit or quit be piped to a command like telnet that is waiting for user input? I need the ability for the curl with telnet to exit immediately or after 5 seconds, as the output will tell me if communication is blocked or accepted.

(what goes here?) | curl -v telnet://host:port

```
some-server01:~ # exit | curl -v telnet://host:port

* Rebuilt URL to: telnet://host:port/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
* Connected to host (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) port (#0)
* RCVD IAC 0

^C
```

Comment: Unless you _really_ need the telnet protocol itself (as opposed to a raw TCP socket, which is what `telnet` is more often used to connect to in modern times), `curl` is often overkill. bash's builtin `/dev/tcp/host/port` support is arguably a lot easier to use, unless your shell was compiled by someone who disabled it.

Comment: More to the point of getting the question into answerable form, though -- what _exactly_ is it you need to have happen? Do you want a socket to be opened, the word `exit` to be sent, the outbound end of the socket to be closed, and then the command to wait until the inbound end of the socket is closed by the remote server? Because if you change `exit |` to `echo "exit" |`, then that's what you'll have already.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't know about `/dev/tcp/host/port` being a bash builtin; it doesn't  exists in bash 4.4  on Solaris.

Comment: @Fravadona, it's a compile-time option, and certainly _can_ be turned on solaris if the people compiling your copy of bash chose to have it be enabled. Note that it won't show up in `ls` no matter what, being a redirection-operator extension, so if you wanted to test it, you'd do something like `exec 3<>/dev/tcp/www.google.com/80`, after which you can use `printf ... >&3` to write to the socket and `read ... <&3` to read from it.

Comment: The goal is for telnet to exit out and not wait for user input. I will be sending this command to many nodes and want to ensure that I get the output of the telnet attempt to the host.  This may need to be done with something else, other than curl -- but it seems like I should be able to either wrapper the curl command to sleep after 5 seconds or just immediately exit out.

Comment: Try: `timeout 5 curl telnet://host:port`